# XSLT to work on a particular group of nodes

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I want a XPath which will consider a particular group and ignore all other groups. Below is my XML code:

```
    <GetBillList>
    <Case>
    <CaseID>...</CaseID> 
    <BillGroup>
    <BillGroupID>...</BillGroupID> 
    </BillGroup>
    </Case>
    <StartDate>2014-01-01</StartDate>
    <GetBillListResponse>
    <Bill>
    <BillStatusCode>
    <BillStatusCode>type description</BillStatusCode>
    <typecode>1</typecode>
    </BillStatusCode>
    <EBillProcessStatusCode>
    <EBillProcessStatusCode>type description</EBillProcessStatusCode>
    <typecode>2</typecode>
    </EBillProcessStatusCode>
    <ToDate>...</ToDate>
    </Bill>
    </GetBillListResponse>
    </GetBillList>
```

XSLT Code:

```
     <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:for-each select="id | typecode">
    <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[not(self::id or self::typecode)]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[name(.) = name(..)]">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

I want it to work on "GetBillListResponse" only ignoring "Case" group & "StartDate" element.

Desired output:

```
    <GetBillList>
    <GetBillListResponse>
    <Bill>
    <BillStatusCode typecode="1">type description</BillStatusCode>
    <EBillProcessStatusCode typecode="2">type description</EBillProcessStatusCode>
    <ToDate>...</ToDate>
    </Bill>
    </GetBillListResponse>
    </GetBillList>
```

Would Appreciate any help on this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I will just base my answer on your current input and XSLT, just add:

```
<xsl:template match="Case|StartDate"/>
```

in your stylesheet.

**EDIT**

if you want to work on the nodes you like to, get this instead:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <GetBillList>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="GetBillList/GetBillListResponse"/>
    </GetBillList>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Hi Joel, Thanks for your reply. Your code is providing the desired output but is it possible to provide that node on which we want to work instead of those nodes which we want to ignore?

Comment: Great. Thanks for the help. I was trying this in a wrong way. Thank you!